# What version of the Bible is translated closest to or directly from the original languages of the texts?

Tags: greek, hebrew, translation-philosophy, tools-of-biblical-studies, aramaic

I have for some time now looked at many versions of the Bible to come to the conclusion that most of the translations that try to interpret the text from the original Aramaic, Hebrew, and Greek languages do so from the English version. Now, I don't know how many other people have met this complication in their studies but if someone has an has found something that is close to what is the original texts, some light would be greatly appreciated. I do have the companion Bible which was printed by kregel company and has a lot of insight into the Bible that most don't, but to me it still carries this problem. I really love my Bible but Id like to dig deeper into the word on a another scale of understanding and I feel translating from the originals is the only way. I know I cannot be first with this mission in mind so if anyone can direct me to someone that has come across this problem with the credentials and scholarly provocations that has made legitimate publications somewhere along these lines, that would mean the world. I pray that this reaches someone like minded and as passionate about the word as I am. So if you can help don't hesitate to share some information. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! I've closed this question because it's very close to the one linked above. You seem to really care about understanding the biblical texts. Please [take our site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and look around to see if some of the specific passages you have questions about have been discussed, as this is a great place to learn. You can also [ask new questions](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The answers to the question linked above provide a good overview of what's available in English translations. If you're really dissatisfied with translations I encourage you to consider learning the original languages. If you stick around, I and others would be happy to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) about this.